# Access QML WebView from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qobject, qwebpage

I have qml file with a webview in it.
I get a reference to that object in c++ but is QObject*
Can i cast it to something similar to QWebView from which i can get the QWebPage object and so?
qobject_cast<> returns NULL if i try QWebView.
It works with cast to QQuickItem but that doesn't really help me much.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The QML WebView element doesn't have a public C++ API. You have two ways to work around this:

1. Use private API. First, add this to the .pro file:

```cs
QT += quick quick-private webkit-private
```

Then include the private headers:

```
#include <private/qquickwebview_p.h>
```

Now you can access the WebView, as long as you get a pointer to it (for example by using `QObject::findChildren` or by passing the `QObject*` from QML to C++. Here I simply assume the WebView is the root object, for simplicity):

```
QQuickWebView * webView = dynamic_cast<QQuickWebView*>(viewer.rootObject());
qDebug() << webView->url();
```

2. Use the generic `QObject` API to access the WebView's properties:

```cs
QObject * webView = viewer.rootObject();
qDebug() << webView->property("url");
```

Comment: for WebEngineView `webengine webengine-private webenginecore webenginecore-private` i added these to work